# Javascript DOM onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom

### This is fixed! Already have a correct answer.

```
("<div class='script' onclick='" + 'open_script(' + data + ', ' + data_name_found + ')' + "'>" + data_name_found + "</div> ")
```

What is wrong with the above code? I am making a project, and am assigning a variable that information to store inside of a div. The variable data is all the data, and data_name_found is the specified name is all the names with other info inside the data variable. The open_script function is supposed to open a div with information about the given script. Sort of like an edit menu, if at all possible, I would prefer not to give out any more code from my project.

Thanks for the help in advance!

EDIT--> The problem is that it won't even trigger the other function. I have been working on this problem for quite a while and can't find out why. May be cause I'm tired, sorry if it's a silly mistake!

Comment: Check your single quotes in the rendered string.

Comment: @torazaburo even though I have the answer, may you expend upon what you're saying? Are you implying the use of return for the functions, as would result in only a line used for a function. I believe it would be more simple to include it inside the parantheses.

Comment: I was asking a question. I was hoping you would answer it, but you decided to be a smart mouth @torazaburo -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more code, but the offending piece of code seems to be:

```
+ 'open_script(' + data + ', ' + data_name_found + ')'
```

If data and data_name_found are strings, they're being outputted into the HTML without quotation marks. Assuming that's the problem, this should fix it:

```
+ 'open_script("' + data + '", "' + data_name_found + '")'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mt_Xing ! I was tired, and had other things on my mind and wasn't thinking straight. But that definitely fixed it. Sorry I couldn't give more code, but for my project I am hoping to sell (Maybe not for a price, but if I do then I'd like the code not to be public, call me paranoid if you wish XD)

Once again, thanks. I completely forgot about the strings!